# Variable in directive's view is not always updated

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

When I call `notificationService.showNotification("Test from controller")` from a controller the message in the directive's view is updated but when I then call `notificationService.showNotification("Test from another service")` from another service the message in the directive's view doesn't get updated.

How should I do to always update `currentNotification.message` in the directive's view when `currentNotification` is updated in the notificationService?

**Update:**

The problem seems to occur when calling `notificationService.showNotification("Test from another service")` from a `setTimeout` function. See plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/qD6OjamFjzOFbg43vj7R
Clicking on "Update from Other Service needs to be done twice for the message to update.

```
angular.module('myApp').service('notificationService',function() {

    var notificationService = {
        currentNotification : {
            message: "",
        },
        showNotification : function(text){
            this.currentNotification.message = text;        
        },

    };

    return notificationService;
});

angular.module('myApp').directive('notificationDirective', function(notificationService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
        },
        templateUrl: 'directive/notification-directive/notification-directive.html',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, fn) {
            scope.currentNotification = notificationService.currentNotification;
        }
    };
});
```

directive/notification-directive/notification-directive.html:

```
<div>
    <div ng-if="currentNotification.message.length > 0" id="notificationWrapper">
        <div class="notification">
            <div class="message"> 
                {{currentNotification.message}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: do you have a plunker?

Comment: You could use `$watch`, try changing your `scope.currentNotification = notificationService.currentNotification` into `scope.$watch(function(){return  notificationService.currentNotification;}, function(){scope.currentNotification = notificationService.currentNotification});`

Comment: Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/qD6OjamFjzOFbg43vj7R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use $timeout which calls $scope.$apply, or you need to call $scope.$apply on your own :

```
myApp.controller('otherCtrl', function($scope, $timeout, notificationService, otherService) {

    $scope.updateFromService = function() {
      console.log("updateFromService");

      $timeout(function(){
        otherService.updateNotification();
      }, 200);
    };    
});
```